# Why can a materials properties be determined with the gs - DFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-functional-theory

Can someone provide me with a text book or explanation as to why in DFT it is sufficient to obtain the ground state at $T=0$ to know a material's properties beyond $T=0$.

I quoting from [here](https://www.nffa.eu/offer/theory-simulation/installation-3/structural-and-ground-state-electronic-properties/)

> Ground-state electronic properties. Electron charge and spin density;
>   Electronic band structure and molecular orbitals; Electronic density
>   of states; Atom-projected density of states; Electron population
>   analysis; Charge transfer and bonding charge analysis; Electron
>   potentials and electron-level alignment, ...

And in the textbook "Electronic Structure" by Richard M. Martin says basically the same thing, see image, but they skim over the details and reasons why and I just don't get it. I have tried to google it but I can't find anything and I couldn't find a direct answer in the references listed (Kittel, Ashcroft, Marder).

[image: W]

I would be so grateful if anyone can explain to me why this is so, or give me a book on where to read it (an actual chapter with the information not just the name of the book please). I am not interested in knowing how each property can be obtained through DFT, but only why the gs is only necessary for some, and why the property in question will be well defined for $T>0$.

Thank you so much in advance. I hope I am not confusing terms now, this is something I have tried to answer for so long without any success.

Comment: 1 year is long to not get an answer, why not copy and paste into https://materials.stackexchange.com?